# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,4) (4,1)

Tags: python, numpy

This code should generate random data within bounds. I understand there is mismatch problem with the arrays, but I'm not sure what it is. Does this mean that the lower and upper bounds defined in the code make it impossible to work?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import qmc

sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=4)

u_bounds = np.array([[2], [10], [10], [2]])
l_bounds = np.array([[0.1], [0.1], [0.1], [0.1]])
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*(u_bounds-(l_bounds)) + (l_bounds)
print(data)
```

The error code

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,4) (4,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you do `a * b`, and the `*` operator is for pointwise multiplication, which is accomplished using broadcasting if required, but the shapes `(100, 4)` and `(4, 1)` can't be broadcast.

You want matrix multiplication, for which you need to use the [`@`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/) operator, or the [`np.matmul()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) function*

```
data = sampler.lhs_method(100) @ (u_bounds - l_bounds) + l_bounds

# or 

data = np.matmul(sampler.lhs_method(100), u_bounds - l_bounds) + l_bounds
```

As [Daniel](/u/4427777) pointed out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129517/operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-100-4-4-1/72129779?noredirect=1#comment127445936_72129779), you'll get a similar error because the matrix multiplication `sampler.lhs_method(100) @ (u_bounds - l_bounds)` is a matrix of shape `(100, 1)` and `l_bounds` is a matrix of shape `(4, 1)`, which can't be added together, so you'll need to check your math.

<sup>*I removed the unnecessary parentheses.</sup>

Comment: You'll get nearly the same error, since your dot product has shape (100,1) and `l_bounds` will have shape (4,1) ; they still won't broadcast.

Comment: @DanielF good point.

Comment: Yes, now I get it, thank you very much both of you